# Android Exo player stream stops after few seconds

Tags: android, exoplayer, drm, widevine

We are deploying OTT in the production environment. So for the application we are using exoplayer version 2.11.4. Currently we have been testing the application and observed that for some Android devices DRM enabled VOD contents cannot play. For some mobile devices it is able to play. I have listed the mobile devices below which we cannot play the DRM contents.

Xiaomi Note 10

Samsung A71

I was able to get the client logs for the above devices and observed the below error.

```
2020-05-28 19:10:43.837 4647-5334/? E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error: index=0, type=video, format=Format(video=900034, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001E, 900034, null, [854, 480, 25.0], [-1, -1]), rendererSupport=NO_UNSUPPORTED_DRM
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0x80000000
        at t60.a(SourceFile:32)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.a(SourceFile:40)
        at d70.a(SourceFile:139)
        at d70.handleMessage(SourceFile:18)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
     Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0x80000000
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_queueSecureInputBuffer(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.queueSecureInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2608)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.y(SourceFile:83)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.a(SourceFile:27)
        at d70.a(SourceFile:139) 
        at d70.handleMessage(SourceFile:18) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```